# Function using regular expression to extract start and end date from string column

Tags: postgresql

have a data set like below and need to extract start date and end date using regular expression in postgresql

```
 OCT-16  
(SEPT-16 )
(JULY-AUG-16) 
( JULY-16 TO OCT-16 ) 
(SEP TO OCT    2016 ) 
( NOV-16 ) 
( NOV-16) 
(October16)
 (SEP - 2016) 
(OCt - 2016) 
( SEPT-16 )
 November 2016
```

Comment: What is the expected result for the above data? What if there is only one date in that column, e.g. is the first line a start or end date? Are two dates always "separated" by `to`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: for this ( JULY-16 TO OCT-16 )  input  expected  result  start_dt: 01-jul-16 and end_dt: 31-OCT-16.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: if only one date is present for instance OCT-16 then start_dt :01-OCT-16 and End_dt : 31-OCT-16